# "rosdep update" broken after ubuntu 12.04.04 amd64 ros-groovy-* updates

Tags: ros, rosdep, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After updating `ros-groovy-*` packages from official `precise` repository found out that `rosdep` is broken.

Terminal:

```
$ rosdep update

reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: Unable to handle 'index' format version '2', please update rosdistro

Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep


rosdep version: 0.10.21

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 118, in rosdep_main 
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 261, in _rosdep_main
    return _no_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 269, in _no_args_handler
    return command_handlers[command](options)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 434, in command_update
    error_handler=update_error_handler)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 422, in update_sources_list
    for d, dist in get_index().distributions.iteritems():

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rosdistrohelper.py", line 58, in get_index
    _RDCache.index = rosdistro.get_index(_RDCache.index_url)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/__init__.py", line 106, in get_index
    return Index(data, base_url)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/index.py", line 51, in __init__
    assert int(data['version']) == 1, "Unable to handle '%s' format version '%d',       
please update rosdistro" % (Index._type, int(data['version']))

AssertionError: Unable to handle 'index' format version '2', please update
    rosdistro
```

The thing which actually bugs me, that `$ dpkg -s python rosdep` reports:

```
Package: python-rosdep
Source: rosdep
Version: 0.10.25-1
```

BUT `$ rosdep --version` , `>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("rosdep").version` and `$ pip search rosdep` returns `0.10.21` as installed version.

Any ideas, how to fix this thing?

I've already tried re-sourcing `setup.bash` on another terminal and reinining deps. Do not think that reinstalling whole damn thing is the nicest solution pinning the problem down to it's roots.

EDIT

Another weird thing:
`$ which rosdep` returns `/usr/local/bin/rosdep`, but trucated `$ dpkg -L python-rosdep` is `/usr/bin/rosdep`. Probably that's the screwing with Python's library locations... :) `Python 2.7` btw.

EDIT:

infact, deleting PiP installed packages, as [suggested](http://answers.ros.org/question/122966/rosdep-update-broken-after-ubuntu-120404-amd64-ros-groovy-updates/?answer=122981#post-id-122981) by [tfoote](http://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) -  `sudo pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` does not return any error, it reports succesfully done:

```
Uninstalling PyYAML:
    Successfully uninstalled PyYAML

Uninstalling bloom:
    Successfully uninstalled bloom

Uninstalling catkin-pkg:
    Successfully uninstalled catkin-pkg

Uninstalling rosdep:
    Successfully uninstalled rosdep

Uninstalling rosdistro:
    Successfully uninstalled rosdistro

Uninstalling rosinstall:
    Successfully uninstalled rosinstall

Uninstalling rospkg:
    Successfully uninstalled rospkg
```

....and lots of other appearently ROS unrelated packages.

**Related issues:**

[@answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org/question/122266/how-can-i-fix-unable-to-handle-index-format-version-2-please-update-rosdistro/?answer=122271#post-id-122271) - sollution to update ros-groovy-*

[bug report rosdep@git](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/291) - closed with note to previoous link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122966/%22rosdep-update%22-broken-after-ubuntu-12.04.04-amd64-ros-groovy-*-updates./) by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The /usr/local location is your problem. You have a pip based installation overlaying your debian packages. You need to invoke pip uninstall repeatedly until it is removed, similarly to this answer. http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-01-27**:
Tried that, didn't work. `sudo pip uninstall rosdep` and `sudo pip search rosdep` told, that same `rosdep 0.10.21` version is **STILL** installed. And, as I told, setting up the ROS environment, `pip` on my side was not used at all. Only thing which was installed using `pip` was `YAML` library. Ages ago. Which was actually updated too.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-27**:
Did you uninstall it multiple times as explained in the link?

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-01-28**:
@tfoote, yes, I did. Unfortunetly, it didn't make any difference at all. I've also tried `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` (as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20385069/1150918 ), still - no change at all.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-28**:
Can you edit your question so show your command and output when you try to uninstall?